# How to change color of a nav dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I was recently working on this Admin theme that I'm creating and as I was creating the nav bar, I ran across this small thing: http://gyazo.com/6e4feee215852ab8fddb534413e24553

So, What I am getting stuck is on the background color of the dropdown once I click on it. I want it to be transparent, which I know how to do via rgba. Here is the HTML for the dropdown also.

```
<div class="apps2"
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                Blood
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The apps2 class within the first div is just positioning the icons (margin/float)

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2014/6/blog_template_using_bootstrap3_part2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Bootstrap files isn't the right approach. That's known as "hacking the core" and sets you up for bothersome maintenance and upgrade problems.

Instead, load a custom CSS file after Bootstrap.css and add your overrides.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/4W3YR/

```
ul.nav li ul {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I eventually found out the problem on my own. Going to the bootstrap.min.css file, had some weird contents within it, but within that, there is a small string (you can ctrl+f 'find' it, just type this: **.nav .open>a:focus** Once you located that, within the { & } symbols, you will find the background-color attribute, you can change that to the rgba, hex or text color you want. :)